# managing MultiLanguage resources

Tags: c#, resources, multilingual

I have created two resource files in my project `GlobalRes.ge.resx` and `GlobalResources.en.resx`

I receive language as an input parameters . I want to know how can I read my values based on language. for example if `string lang = "en"` then by `globalres.welcome` I should see WOLCOME but if I choose `lang = "ge"` then `globalres.welcome` should be willkommen 
(I have already created the welcome line in both files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Resource Designer will load the appropriate text based on the CurrentUICulture

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
bCancel.Text = Resource.Cancel;
```

In .NET 4.5 and later you can use the following properties to set the DefaultThreadCurrentCulture & DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture  culture.

```
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
```